# Procedure with Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, procedure

I have similar problem: [Stored Procedure with Dynamic Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441024/stored-procedure-with-dynamic-query) but I can't do that. I have 100 similar tables, and I want to make dynamic procedure, but it doesn't work.

```
create or alter procedure Tab  
(
    @z nvarchar(50) = ISNULL,
    @s varchar(30) = ISNULL,
    @l nvarchar(30) = ISNULL)
as 
begin
    Declare @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(50)

    exec ('select * from'  + @l)  as p 
           join z as z on p.C = z.C 
           where @z in (home, away)
             and p.s = @s 
             and z = @z
 end
```

---

Ok so I have 100 tables country c in mssql server and I don't want to write 100 stored procedures to each other, but instead write one for all of that.

This is the code for the procedure for one table

```
create or alter procedure Tabela  
    (@zwyc  nvarchar(50) = ISNULL ,
     @season nvarchar(50) = ISNULL ,
     @lig nvarchar(50) = ISNULL)
as 
begin
    Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    set @SQL = 'select * from '+@lig+' as p 
    join zwyc z on p.Country=z.Country 
    where '+@zwyc+' in  (home, away) 
    and p.season = '+@season+' and z.zwyc = '+@zwyc
    exec (@sql)
go
```

and now I want to create a dynamic query in a stored procedure to connect to all countries POR , GER , SWE , ENG ...

sample view table POL (@lig)

```
IDPOL   Country League  Season  data    Time    Home    Away    
1   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-17  17:00:00.0000000    Pogon Szczecin  Zaglebie    
2   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-17  19:30:00.0000000    Piast Gliwice   Gornik Z.   
3   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-18  12:30:00.0000000    Jagiellonia Podbeskidzie    
4   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-18  14:45:00.0000000    Widzew Lodz Slask Wroclaw   
5   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-18  17:00:00.0000000    Lech Poznan Ruch    
6   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-19  13:30:00.0000000    Wisla   GKS Belchatow   
7   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-19  16:00:00.0000000    Legia   Korona Kielce   
8   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-20  17:30:00.0000000    Lechia Gdansk   Polonia Warszawa    
9   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-24  17:00:00.0000000    Zaglebie    Piast Gliwice   
10  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-24  19:30:00.0000000    Jagiellonia Gornik Z.
```

SQL Server returns this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tabela, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 1]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

I change table name

Here is the joined query for one country

```
select top 10 
    IDPOL, p.country, p.league, p.Season, data, time ,home, away 
from 
    POL p
join 
    zwyciezcy z on p.Country = z.Country 
where 
    p.Season = '2012/2013'
    and z.Zwyciezca = 'Slask Wroclaw'
    and (home = 'Slask Wroclaw' or away = 'Slask Wroclaw')
```

and here is the result

```
IDPOL   country league  Season  data    time    home    away    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
4   Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-18  14:45:00.0000000    Widzew Lodz Slask Wroclaw   
14  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-08-26  13:30:00.0000000    Slask Wroclaw   Korona Kielce   
23  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-09-02  16:00:00.0000000    Slask Wroclaw   Ruch    
25  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-09-14  17:00:00.0000000    Podbeskidzie    Slask Wroclaw   
38  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-09-23  13:30:00.0000000    Slask Wroclaw   GKS Belchatow   
46  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-09-30  13:30:00.0000000    Gornik Z.   Slask Wroclaw   
55  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-10-07  16:00:00.0000000    Slask Wroclaw   Polonia Warszawa    
62  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-10-21  13:30:00.0000000    Lechia Gdansk   Slask Wroclaw   
70  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-10-28  13:30:00.0000000    Slask Wroclaw   Zaglebie    
80  Poland  Ekstraklasa 2012/2013   2012-11-05  17:30:00.0000000    Pogon Szczecin  Slask Wroclaw
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? *"but it doesn't work"* is too broad. It would help if you could start with what you're trying to accomplish with dynamic SQL and then explain why the linked solution doesn't help you.

Comment: exec ('select * from'  + @l)  as p    needs a space after from and before single quote.  But more importantly, the remainder of the SQL needs to be one entire single text, that is given at once to the Exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this SQL Server, or MySQL, or Oracle, or MS Access, or .... what?  Please change the TAG associated with the question. Answers will need to change accordingly.

Rather than starting a new Answer, please Edit the first question, and at the end of what was there add a separator of `>>>>` and then paste your corrections or revisions, keeping all that was above it.

Then, be aware that

```
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(50)
```

needs to be `(500)` (or more) because what we come up with may be a long SQL.

What I got from 2nd SQL was

```
select * 
from LLL as p 
join z as z on p.C = z.C 
wher
```

which was truncated after 50 chars.

Also, it may be continued on several lines, so let it wrap for readability.  What does it look like without params?

Also, the arguments should not be single letters  (@z, @s, @l, as well as s, z, p, ...) but should be descriptive.

Finally, we need to start with what the output is going to look like.

The SQL procedure seems only to have a select with a join.  Is this to be run 100 times? 100 results?

Or are we trying to JOIN 100 tables into ONE result?

Finally let us see some Inputs.  So please show us those table names by running and pasting the 1st 5 or 10 rows from

```
USE StackOver-or-your-db-name; 

SELECT name, max_column_id_used 
FROM sys.Tables  (maybe, WHERE name like 'xxx*')
```

And the structure of one input DDL.

And the first few rows of data in a table, say POR

When you say it doesn't work, tell us the line in the SQL and the Message received.

---------- Feb 24  1am

Good progress.  Lets not create proc 1st, but rather get the sql to work.
Please change arg  @zwyc to have a different name than the table name to avoid confusion; maybe @cname.

Please print a few rows of table zwyc that is being joined. 
Here is what I am testing with.  I added lots of pairs of quotes to surround the varchar args. And right before EXEC, I added a

```
 Print @sql
```

to  look at the SQL that will execute.  Then change my sql arg values to what works for you, 
and paste back into your area above so I know what you tried... noting any further problems...

```
 Declare
         @zwyc  nvarchar(50) = 'Poland' ,
         @season nvarchar(50) = '2012/2013' ,
         @ateam nvarchar(50) = 'Wisla',
         @lig nvarchar(50) = '[StackOver].[dbo].[DynamicQueryPOL]'

        Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
        set @SQL = 'select * from ' + @lig + ' as p 
        join zwyc z on p.Country=z.Country 
        where ( p.home =  ''' + @ateam + '''   OR  p.away  = ''' + @ateam + ''' ) 
        and p.season = ''' + @season + ''' and z.zwyc = ''' + @zwyc + ''''
        print @sql
        --exec (@sql)
```

---------- Feb 24  13:30 PDT

Are the results good?  With the revised pairs of single quotes around the args it seems to work.

Are all 3 args always provided? Or might some of them be null/not supplied?

I notice that 
p.country in the listing is always 'Poland'

Why do we join?  Do we get only 1 row back?  Seems like we get 12 or so rows...

```
join zwyciezcy z  on p.Country=z.Country
```

And those 12 rows are then filtered by Team name to only one.

```
where ::: z.Zwyciezca='Slask Wroclaw'
```

But we use no other columns from table zwyciezcy z.  So why is the join performed?

**Please print a few rows of table zwyciezcy  that is being joined.**

Answer (score 0):

**Issue in Your Query:**
In you dynamic query you're not handling `z.Zwyciezca = 'Slask Wroclaw'` correctly. The way you're handling it is: `z.Zwyciezca = Slask Wroclaw` without `'`

```
select *
from 
    POL p
join 
    zwyciezcy z on p.Country = z.Country 
where 
    p.Season = '2012/2013'
    and z.Zwyciezca = 'Slask Wroclaw'
    and (home = 'Slask Wroclaw' or away = 'Slask Wroclaw')
```

Example Dynamic Query for above should be like:

```
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    set @SQL = 'select * from '+@lig+' as p 
    join SomeTable z on p.columnname= z.columnname
    where p.columnName in  (''home'', ''away'') 
    and p.anothercolumn= '''+@season + ''''

    print @SQL
    exec (@sql)
```